# Getting error message as "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element" while running the SOAP Script

Tags: citrus-framework

I have used the Citrus Framework to test SOAP. Here the payload I have given and which has to fetch from the XML file but in the console its pointed to a different Location.

```
soap()
      .client(todoClient)
      .send()
      .soapAction("loginSOAP")
      .payload(new ClassPathResource("data/loginSOAP.xml"));  

soap()
      .client(todoClient)
      .receive()          
      .payload(new ClassPathResource("data/loginSOAPResponse.xml"));
```

While running it I am getting an error as `Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://soap.myapp.mycomm.org/", local:"userName"). Expected elements are <{}password>,<{}userName>`.

can you please help me here, Why i am getting the error.

*Update*
**Here is the Stack Trace**

```
10:28:06,169 DEBUG estExecutionListener| After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@1bdaa23d testClass = SOAP, testInstance = com.consol.citrus.integration.Demo.SOAP@ec2bf82, testMethod = TestPost@SOAP, testException = com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@79f227a9 testClass = SOAP, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.consol.citrus.config.CitrusSpringConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method ann
otated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
10:28:06,189 DEBUG estExecutionListener| After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@1bdaa23d testClass = SOAP, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@79f227a9 testClass = SOAP, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.consol.citrus.config.CitrusSpringConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
FAILED: TestPost({Param_18=, Param_17=, Param_16=, Param_15=, Param_9=, Param_14=, Param_8=, Param_13=, Param_7=, Param_12=, Param_6=, Param_11=, Param_5=, Param_10=, Param_4=, Runmode=Y, Param_3=, Param_2=admin, Param_1=admin})
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:236)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.doExecute(TestCase.java:145)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.Citrus.run(Citrus.java:281)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod(TestNGCitrusTest.java:136)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTestDesigner.invokeTestMethod(TestNGCitrusTestDesigner.java:73)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:111)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://soap.myapp.mycomm.org/", local:"userName"). Expected elements are <{}password>,<{}userName> 
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
    at com.consol.citrus.ws.client.WebServiceClient$InternalFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(WebServiceClient.java:243)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:531)
    at com.consol.citrus.ws.client.WebServiceClient.send(WebServiceClient.java:126)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.SendMessageAction.doExecute(SendMessageAction.java:118)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.dsl.actions.DelegatingTestAction.doExecute(DelegatingTestAction.java:54)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:229)
    ... 31 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

219875 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219875 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
219875 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - AFTER TEST SUITE: SUCCESS
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - CITRUS TEST RESULTS
219876 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219883 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus -  SOAP.TestPost([{Param_18=, Param_17=, Param_16=, Param_15=, Param_9=, Param_14=, Param_8=, Param_13=, Param_7=, Param_12=, Param_6=, Param_11=, Param_5=, Param_10=, Param_4=, Runmode=Y, Param_3=, Param_2=admin, Param_1=admin}])  FAILED
219884 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus -  FAILURE: Caused by: SoapFaultClientException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://soap.myapp.mycomm.org/", local:"userName"). Expected elements are <{}password>,<{}userName> 
219884 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219885 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - TOTAL:    1
219886 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - FAILED:   1 (100.0%)
219886 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - SUCCESS:  0 (0.0%)
219886 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - 
219886 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.Citrus - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
220110 [main] INFO com.consol.citrus.report.HtmlReporter - Generated HTML test report

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error stack trace. helps a lot to understand what is exactly going on. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting here is not raised in the test case but on the server that you are calling. Citrus as client receives the error as SOAP fault which causes the `SoapFaultClientException`. Obviously the server is not happy with the content of `loginSOAP.xml` that you send as payload.

Please also check the SOAP server logs. You should see the error here as it has been raised during the processing of your request.